# Change login link to logout on certain pages using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to change my login link to logout if there is a session created.

I used the code from an existing question on stackoverflow however it did not work.

This is the HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="newBooking.php">New Booking</a></li>
        <li><a href="bookings.php">Bookings</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['who'])): ?>
            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li> 
        <?php else :?>  
            <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li> 
        <?php endif; ?>
        <li><a href="flights.php">Flights</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is the PHP code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$user = $_SESSION['who'];
require_once('dbconn.php');
$sql = "select fname,lname,email,address,suburb,state,postcode,phone from customer where id = '$user' ";
$rs = $dbConn->query($sql);

if (! $_SESSION['who']) {
    header("location: login.php");
}
```

My user variable comes from my session in my login.php page

I am trying to use this code on all my pages. However if the user is not logged in it still keeps saying out log out.

I have checked to make sure there was an active session and my session was working correctly.

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['who']`?

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: @Nick  the session starts on my login page- when the user logs in it matches the details against my database and if it is successfully will create a new session

Comment: @Laif when i am logged in and go to a page it still displays login instead of logout

Comment: echo the session variable, what do you get in both scenarios?

Comment: What are you doing with this variable? `$user = $_SESSION['who'];` it is never used

Comment: @Laif the session variable is the customerID in my database it is used in my select statement for my sql to get the information about the customer logged in

Comment: You do realise you're showing the login if the session exists and the logout if it doesn't right?

Comment: @WilliamAwad You are not assigning it correctly, check my answer.

Comment: i corrected it however my session is not empty, my user variable is empty which is why i am assigning it to the session..

after changing the code, once i click on a page it displays logout even if i am not logged in

Comment: @WilliamAwad You are not assigning it to the session, you are assigning the session to it. You wrote it backwards. It is showing logout because you have your logic backwards as well. I acknowledged all of this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$user = $_SESSION['who'];` to `$_SESSION['who'] = $user;`

The first one is assigning the empty session variable to a variable named user, which is never used, the opposite does what you want, setting the session variable to be equal to the user variable.

Then, change `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['who'])): ?>` to `<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['who'])): ?>` because you want the logout button to show when the user is logged in, right now it is vice-versa.

Comment: could you please explain how i have set my variable the wrong way around?

currently i have $user = $_SESSION['who']; where the session contains the value '14' which is the ID of the customer logged in. ( i have echoed out the session and returns 14)
so now wouldn't $user contain the value 14?
i say this because i have a sql like this 
insert into customer (customerID, ... , ... ) values ($user, ... , ...) which works correctly

Comment: Yes, it would, however in this code you are ever actually changing the value of $_SESSION[‘who’] to anything. Wouldn’t you want the session who variable to reflect who the user is?

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code. You've set the session and set the condition in view in the wrong way. Below is the edited code. It may help you.

**View Code:**

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="profile.php">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="newBooking.php">New Booking</a></li>
            <li><a href="bookings.php">Bookings</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['who'])): ?> 
              <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li> 
            <?php else :?>  
              <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li><a href="flights.php">Flights</a></li>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
     session_start();

     $_SESSION['who'] = $user;
     require_once('dbconn.php');
     $sql = "select fname,lname,email,address,suburb,state,postcode,phone from customer where id = '$user' ";
     $rs = $dbConn->query($sql);

     if (!$_SESSION['who']) {
         header("location: login.php");
     }


?>
```

To know more about PHP session, please visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

or

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: This is different from my answer how?

Comment: i think i presented fully workable code. May i know, why did my code get downvote?

Comment: Stack overflow isn’t a code writing service, therefore, you don’t get extra points for having “fulling working code” (which in this context apparently just means copy and pasting more of the example code than I did)

Comment: @Laif why downvote? Let them understand by messaging the thing you described earlier. But you didn't. Why are they here - to learn or to teach?

Comment: They are here to both teach and learn, so not sure what you’re saying there. The entire purpose of the downvote function is to discourage discourse that does not add anything constructive to the conversation, which is literally exactly what I am saying, that nothing new was added. @unclexo

Comment: @Laif No! I think the answer from Towsif, to me, is more clear and constructive than you. And this kind of answer can make a newbie understand well. I think you understand my point.

Comment: @Laif Please don't take it otherwise. :)